# Onchange wont work for select when table form is at start

Tags: javascript, forms, html-table, onchange

I am having a problem with a form and using an onchange for a select in that form.  When I start the form right before the 2 selects it works wonderfully,  but when I move the form outside the table (to include everything), the onchange will not work.  Any ideas as to why?

Here is my form:

```
<table border="0" class="signUp">
    <tr><td align="center" class= "signUpfont"> Sign up for FREE </td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" text="First Name" class='signUpinput' id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" class='signUpinput' id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" class='signUpinput' id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" class='signUpinput' id="email2" name="email2"  placeholder="Re-enter Email"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="password" class='signUpinput' id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Password"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><form name="form1" action="submit.php" method='POST'>   
                    <select name="country" onchange="window.getSchools()" style="color: white; background-color: #2B4478;">
        <option value="0">Select State</option>
        <option value="louisiana">Louisiana</option>
        <option value="texas">Texas</option>
        <option value="alabama">Alabama</option>
        <option value="mississippi">Mississippi</option>
    </select>
    <br>
        <select name="school" style="color: white;background-color: #2B4478;">
        <option value="">Select School</option>
    </select></td></tr>

    <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" style="color:white; background-color:#2B4478; width: 100px;margin-left: 52px;"></td></tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

and here is my onchange function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getSchools()
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        try{
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
           }catch(e)
           {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
               }

        if(xmlhttp)
            {
                var form = document['form1'];
                var country = form['country'].value;

                xmlhttp.open("GET", "getSchools.php?country="+country, true);

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
                {
                    if(this.readyState == 4)
                    {
                        var s = document.createElement('select');
                        s.name = "school";
                        s.style.color = "white";
                        s.style.background = "#2b4478";
                        s.innerHTML = this.responseText;

                        if(form['school'])
                        {
                            form.replaceChild(s, form['school']);
                        }else
                            form.insertBefore(s, form['submit']);
                    }
                }                   

                xmlhttp.send(null)
            }
    }
```

Comment: Both `<form>` tags must be either inside one `<td>` or outside the `<table>`, so I'm surprised it works the way you say it does. Are you placing both opening **and** closing tags outside the table?

Answer (score 0):

Your event is not being fired because you do not explicitly define 'window.getSchools'. So you have two options.

### Option 1

Fix the onchange inline handler:

```
<select name="country" onchange="getSchools()">
    <option value="0">Select State</option>
    <option value="louisiana">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="texas">Texas</option>
    <option value="alabama">Alabama</option>
    <option value="mississippi">Mississippi</option>
</select>
```

Define your event:

```
getSchools = function()
{
    //put your code here
    alert("fired");
}
```

### Option 2

Keep your same html:

```
<select name="country" onchange="window.getSchools()">
    <option value="0">Select State</option>
    <option value="louisiana">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="texas">Texas</option>
    <option value="alabama">Alabama</option>
    <option value="mississippi">Mississippi</option>
</select>
```

Fix your event handler:

```
window.getSchools = function()
{
    //put your code here
    alert("fired");
}
```

You can see the official documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope)

You also have malformed HTML. You close the  element before closing the  element. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yqNZp/1/) for a working example.

I would definitely suggest going through the [JavaScript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript), it may seem tedious when starting out, but trust me when I say that it will save you quite literally days of your life in debugging and troubleshooting :)